# RxJS append observable to observable array list in typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

How to add `Observable<News>` to an array of observable ?

```
newsArray: Observable<Array<any>>;

addNews(newsId: number) {
   let news = this.newsService.getNewNews(newsId); // this returns a Observable<News> type.

  //I want to add `news` to `newsArray` to display it in UI.
}
```

HTML:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of (newsArray | async)">
  <div>{{item.Id}}: {{item.DataValue}}</div>
</li>
```

Any other operators to use?

I tried `BehaviourSubject` but it displays only one value at a time. I want to display add items that I am appending to an arrray.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use scan to accumulate news

```
news$:Observable<any>
loadMore$=new Subject<number>()

ngOnInit(){
 this.news$=this.loadMore$
 .switchMap((newsId)=>this.newsService.getNewNews(newsId))
 .scan((acc,curr)=>{
    acc.push(curr)
    return acc
 },[]).startWith(null)
}

addNews(newsId: number) {
  this.loadMore$.next(newsId);
}
```

HTML

```
<li *ngFor="let item of (news$ | async)">
  <div>{{item.Id}}: {{item.DataValue}}</div>
</li>
```

Comment: but I want to add news on a button click event, also there is an NewsId that I want to pass it to API based on that news will be fectched.

Comment: And if we wanted to add to the top of the array it’s just a normal acc.unshift?

Comment: yep you are right.

Comment: Thanks. Also are you allowed to put in an if else statement inside scan? Or do we have to use filter? Depending on what button was pressed I either need to do unshift or push

Comment: inside scan it is just normal sync code , yes you can