# How to append an Observable array to existing one consumed via Angular async pipes?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

I've got a service call that loads ten items onto the screen. When users click a "View More" button, I send another call to the service with different paging arguments. What's the best way to gracefully append the new array of items from the second call into the existing array emitted by the first call?

My example below technically works, but it resets the original observable, refreshing all items on the screen, rather than just adding the new ones. Thoughts? Could Subjects help with this?

```
private onViewMoreClicked(): void {
    this.pageOffset += this.pageLimit;

    const moreItems$ = this.itemService.get(
        this.pageLimit,
        this.pageOffset
    );

    this.items$ = forkJoin(this.items$, moreItems$).pipe(
        map(([a, b]) => [...a, ...b])
    );
```

Comment: use trackBy if don't want refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48677496/251614) or this...

Setup in the on-init…

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.pageOffset = 0;

    this.items$ = this.nextPage$.pipe(
        // load first batch when Angular async pipe subscribes
        startWith(this.pageOffset),
        // switch observable to output of getMessages
        switchMap(offset => this.itemService.get(
            this.pageLimit,
            offset
        )),
        // add newly-emitted batch to previously-emitted items
        scan((acc, curr) => {
            acc.push(...curr);
            return acc;
        }, [])
    );
}
```

And this should be the view more click handler…

```
private onViewMoreClicked(): void {
   this.pageOffset += this.pageLimit;

   // load new items into message$  
    this.nextPage$.next(this.pageOffset);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With the code you have right now, I think you could do change your forkJoin into this

```
this.items$ = [...this.items$, ...moreItems$];
```

But your `itemService` doesn't look right. I think you want it to be setup something like this

```
this.itemService(this.pageLimit, this.pageOffset).subscribe(res => {
    this.items$ = [...this.items$, ...res];
});
```

Comment: I see where you're going with this, but for me, subscribing in the component code to the service call to get more items defeats the purpose of using Angular async pipes -- not having to remember to unsubscribe. That's why my service call does not include a subscribe(); Angular will automatically subscribe and unsubscribe with async pipes.